# Работа с Pypy в консоли linux (ubuntu +20)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypy

Пишу бота для VK (python 3.7). Хотел попробовать ускорить бота, запустив его через pypy (естественно, бот на VPS). Запускаю файл, но мне пишет, что не видит библиотеку `vk_api`. Она установлена в оригинальном python.

Помогите с установкой Pypy модулей?

PS Пробовал гуглить, но у меня не получилось установить модули...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342075/install-pip-on-pypy → `pip install vk-api`

Comment: Удалось как-то обойти эту ошибку. Команды по ссылке не помогли или помогли частично. В начале файла пишу: `#!/usr/bin/env pypy`. Вроде он ускорился.

Comment: Файл не работает быстрее, просто кастыль.

Comment: В случае с ботом pypy я думаю не сильно должен ускорить.

Comment: если в файле нет математики - то и пайпай не нужен

Comment: Если тормозит, например, из-за задержек передачи данных по сети, то использование pypy никак не поможет. Вообще, нужно код смотреть.

Comment: Математика есть в боте, в этом и нужда подключения pypy.